# Annotation with Line plot in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I working with matplotlib and below you can see my data and my line plot.

```
data = {
         'Year': ["2000","2001","2002","2003","2004","2005","2006","2007","2008","2009","2010","2011","2012","2013","2014","2015","2016","2017","2018","2019","2020","2021"],
         'Sales':[8.7,5.7,5.8,5.6,5.5,5.3,5,4.8,4.2,4.2,4.1,4.1,4.1,4.1,4.7,4.6,4.8,4.9,5.3,5.4,5.7,5.7],
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Year',
                                   'Sales',
                                   ])
df.plot(x='Year', kind='line', stacked=True,legend=None,xlabel='',ylabel='In percentage (%)')
```

Now I want to add specific annotation on the line of this plot in year 2000, 2010 and 2020.
Annotation text are: For 2000 `"GST 10 %, 15 and 20%"` for 2010 `"GST 10 %, 18 and 25%"` and for 2020 `"GST 15 %, 19 and 21%"`. Below you can see how need to look.

[image]

So can anybody help me how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any specific reason you inputted the year as a string? Anyway, I converted it to a number for convenience. To annotate, you can use [`ax.annotate`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.annotate.html).

Here's the code:

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data = {
         'Year': ["2000","2001","2002","2003","2004","2005","2006","2007","2008","2009","2010","2011","2012","2013","2014","2015","2016","2017","2018","2019","2020","2021"],
         'Sales':[8.7,5.7,5.8,5.6,5.5,5.3,5,4.8,4.2,4.2,4.1,4.1,4.1,4.1,4.7,4.6,4.8,4.9,5.3,5.4,5.7,5.7],
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Year',
                                   'Sales',
                                   ], dtype=float)
ax = df.plot(x='Year', kind='line', stacked=True,legend=None,xlabel='',ylabel='In percentage (%)', marker='o')

pos_xy1 = df.iloc[0, :].to_numpy()
pos_xy2 = df.iloc[9, :].to_numpy()
pos_xy3 = df.iloc[20, :].to_numpy()

ax.annotate('GST 10%,\n15 and 20%', xy=pos_xy1, xytext=pos_xy1+np.array([-1, 0.5]), arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle='->'))
ax.annotate('GST 10%,\n18 and 25%', xy=pos_xy2, xytext=pos_xy2+np.array([-1.5, 0.5]), arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle='->'))
ax.annotate('GST 15%,\n19 and 21%', xy=pos_xy3, xytext=pos_xy3+np.array([-3, 0.5]), arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle='->'))

ax.set_ylim(top=10)
ax.grid(which='major', axis='y')
```

Result:

[image]